# Is it possible to copy bitbucket's "all branches graph" history to git?

Tags: git, bitbucket

I want to migrate my code from BitBuket to GitHub, and I also wanna migrate my commit history to git.

Is it possible?
If yes, how?

Comment: Bitbucket already uses Git, so I don't understand your question.

Comment: It's difficult to tell what is being asked here, and this question cannot be reasonably answered in its current form. Please provide the context, and/or post code samples of what you have done (i.e.: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com))

Comment: Do you mean Git_Hub_? That's a different thing than Git. GitHub and Bitbucket have similar relationships with Git. Have you searched "migrate bitbucket to github"? I'm sure you'll find some helpful resources if you do.

Comment: My bad, i know how to migrate the code from bitbucket to github. But, i don't know how to migrate the commit history of bitbucket to github. So that i can still know the different commit message.

Answer (score 1):

> But, i don't know how to migrate the commit history of bitbucket to github

It should be as easy as:

```
 cd /path/to/local/clone
 git remote add github /url/to/new/empty/GitHub/repo
 git push --mirror github
```

The [`--mirror` part of the `git push` command](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push#Documentation/git-push.txt---mirror) should push *everything* (all branches/tags) to your new GitHub repository.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is cloning the git repository so that your commit history and branches remains intact.

```
git clone --bare https://username@bitbucket.org/username/OLD-PROJECT.git
cd OLD-PROJECT.git
git push --mirror https://github.com/username/NEW-PROJECT.git
cd ..
rm -rf OLD-PROJECT.git
```